# Import own python modules in nextflow script block?

Tags: python, nextflow

I created a python script called `utilities.py` in `bin/` directory:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import io 


def print_info(in_df, fname_base):
    buffer = io.StringIO()
    df = in_df.copy()
    df.info(buf=buffer)
    s = buffer.getvalue()
    with open(fname_base+"_info.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
        f.write(s)

def print_desc(in_df, fname_base):
    df = in_df.copy()
    desc = df.describe()
    desc.to_csv(fname_base+"_desc.tsv", sep = '\t')
    
def print_data(in_df, fname_base):
    df = in_df.copy()
    print_info(df, fname_base)
    print_desc(df, fname_base)
    df.to_csv(fname_base+".tsv", sep = '\t')
```

and made it executable with `chmod +x`. I would like to use these functions in a several script blocks in various processes in my workflow. Currently when I try importing a function from my utilities module:

```
#!/bin/bash nextflow 

process transform_data {

    input:
    path(data)

    output:
    path("out.tsv"), emit: out_data

    script:
    """
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import pandas as pd
    import io
    from utilities import print_info
    """
}
```

I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".command.sh", line 4, in <module>
      from utilities import print_info
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

Is it possible to import own modules in this way?

Comment: try `from .utilities import print_info`

Comment: Sure - your utilities directory should be in directory, which is added to PATH. Then, it's no problem.

Comment: @Pallie Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when I try that.

Comment: @DawidGacek The `utilities.py` file is located in `bin` directory which according to Nextflow documentation should already have been added to PATH:
https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-invoke-custom-scripts-and-tools

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Nextflow are you using?
I tested with v22.04.5 and the following works:

My setup is little bit different, instead of specifying `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, I directly invoked a python script (`test.py`) which has `from utilities import print_info` inside it, and it works fine.

```
script:
    """
      test.py
    """
```

Note that the following won't work: `from .utilities import print_info`. Therefore, you can import custom Python module with Nextflow.